# Android best way to get pagination scroll for lazy loading with fast scroll

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

In my application, I am populating information in UI from sqlite database using recyclerview. I had implemented infinite scroll using limit, offset sqlite queries which after query result populate POJOs for recyclerview. However, now I also need to implement a fast scroll feature which would by principle will be against pagination for lazy loading purpose. I am wondering what will be best architecture to achieve both simultaneously. I dont want to load all objects from database in POJO's in the beginning for lesser start time but eventually need a fast scroll over all content.

Comment: you need [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b)

Comment: @pskink On doubt, the table I have has some heavy data and lots of rows. If  I use cursoradapter, wouldn't it take lot of time initially to load the cursor and only after that, it will start populating the recyclerview? Actually I was using the same code before and then moved to current implementation of getting data in batches and converting to POJO and passing to recyclerview, but at the time didnt had as much data in application.

Comment: so measure the time of getting the `Cursor` and fetching the data in both solutions and compare the results

Comment: what do you mean lots of rows? 10k? 100k? 1M? more?

Comment: @pskink could go upto 10k. However I am storing a json field in one of the columns which can have upto 1000 words

Comment: so try that `CursorRecyclerAdapter` or even its easier brother `SimpleCursorRecyclerAdapter` that you can find [here](http://codeshare.io/nooA7) with the simple Activity#onCreate code

Comment: Moved back to cursorRecyclerAdapter and its working. Thanks.